# Is it "sloped ceiling/roof", "sloping ceiling/roof" or "slanted ceiling/roof"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, phrases, terminology

Googling these terms shows all of these terms appear to be in use. Which ones are correct/commonly accepted?

Comment: **pitched** would be another possibility as well.

Comment: "commonly accepted" is not clear.  Do you mean how does the average person describe the roof, or how are such roofs designated by people who work with roofs in some manner?  Roofers, builders, solar panel installers, etc?

Answer (score 1):

All of those terms work in the right context, but slanted might have a slightly different connotation. Often **slanted** has the *implication* that something is **mistakenly askew**, rather than skewed on purpose. Otherwise, like you said, all of these are fairly common and essentially have the same meaning.